# SQL : Turning rows into columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need to turning the value of a row into column - for example:

```
SELECT s.section_name, 
       s.section_value 
  FROM tbl_sections s
```

this outputs :

```
section_name   section_value
-----------------------------
sectionI       One
sectionII      Two
sectionIII     Three
```

desired output :

```
sectionI      sectionII      sectionIII
-----------------------------------------
One           Two            Three
```

Comment: What happens if you have more than one row with a section_name of `sectionI`, but a different value? Do you display another row?  If so, what should be displayed under sectionII and sectionIII?  Where do the empty columns go if there are a mismatched number of entries for each section_name?  In a general sense, what you're trying to do isn't very well defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably better done client-side in the programming language of your choice.

You absolutely need to know the section names in advance to turn them into column names.

**Updated answer for Oracle 11g (using the [new PIVOT operator](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/PivotAndUnpivotOperators_11gR1.php)):**

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT section_name, section_value FROM tbl_sections)
PIVOT
  MAX(section_value) 
    FOR (section_name) IN ('sectionI', 'sectionII', 'sectionIII')
```

**For older versions, you could do some self-joins:**

```
WITH
  SELECT section_name, section_value FROM tbl_sections
AS 
  data
SELECT
   one.section_value 'sectionI', 
   two.section_value 'sectionII', 
   three.section_value 'sectionIII'
FROM 
   select selection_value from data where section_name = 'sectionI' one
  CROSS JOIN
   select selection_value from data where section_name = 'sectionII' two
  CROSS JOIN
   select selection_value from data where section_name = 'sectionIII' three
```

**or also use the MAX trick and "aggregate":**

```
SELECT 
   MAX(DECODE(section_name, 'sectionI', section_value, '')) 'sectionI',
   MAX(DECODE(section_name, 'sectionII', section_value, '')) 'sectionII',
   MAX(DECODE(section_name, 'sectionIII', section_value, '')) 'sectionIII'
FROM tbl_sections
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, is there any way that we don't know about the name of the section and will turn into columns?

Comment: This is going to create a pretty frightening cross product, isn't it?  @sprenna No.

Comment: No. Not with SQL alone. Table names, columns names and such need to be known before you run the query. Maybe with native dynamic SQL via PL/SQL. But that is equivalent to doing it "client-side in the programming language of your choice."

Comment: @gfortune: If there is only one row, it is not that frightening. But yes, this does not scale well to many rows and/or columns.

Comment: This is not the optimal solution, a pivot would suffice.